# How can I rotate the arrow icon on active Bootstrap 4 dropdown?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass, drop-down-menu

I have dropdown from Bootstrap 4. I need to make the arrow to rotate up when the dropdown is open.
Does anyone know how to do this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Kate, what have you tried? Please see [ask]. It's expected that you make an effort and ask a specific question about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage [Bootstrap's events for Dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/#events).

```css
body {
  padding: 30px; /* demo only */
}

.rotated::after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <span class="dropdown-item">Dropdown content</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$('#dropdownMenu').on('show.bs.dropdown', function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').addClass('rotated');
}).on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').removeClass('rotated');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.parentNode.addEventListener("click", function() {
    btn.classList.toggle("rotated");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px; /* demo only */
}

.rotated::after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <span class="dropdown-item">Dropdown content</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Good solution, but I'd probably be more specific about which class you add event handlers and classes to. There could be many buttons on the page. :)